# AMD Radeon HD 7310 HDMI Functionality on any Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, video, radeon, hdmi, xbmc

I found a great deal on a desktop pc that I would like to run and a media server with ubuntu and xbmc. It uses an AMD Radeon HD 7310 and supports HDMI output via Windows 8. I need to know that ubuntu & some sort of drivers can push video out before I make this purchase. Full specs on the unit can be found [here](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Desktop+-+4GB+Memory+-+500GB+Hard+Drive/8982144.p?id=1218960126937&skuId=8982144&st=gateway&cp=1&lp=3#tab=specifications).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AMD GPU's do work in ubuntu, although their linux drivers are not as feature rich as other brands, such as not having HD audio support. You will need the proprietary drivers for improved xbmc performance. I suggest you try the xvba branch of XBMC as enables GPU acceleration with AMD GPU's, [this thread on the xbmc forums](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=116996) has a comprehensive how-to guide with driver recommendations.